# Python paramiko sending sudo password and other data to command

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I want to change Ubuntu user password using ssh and Python.

```
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect('xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', username='xxx', password='xxx')
stdin,stdout,stderr = client.exec_command('sudo passwd test1')
stdin.write('passForSudo' + '\n')
stdin.write('newPassForUser' + '\n')
stdin.write('newPassForUser' + '\n')
stdin.flush()
```

Why this doesn't work? I can't find solution(

Comment: How does it fail? What line does it fail on? Do you get any error messages? What do they say?

Answer (score 0):

by default, sudo don't read password from stdin, but from terminal.

man sudo give :

```
...
-S, --stdin
             Write the prompt to the standard error and read the password from the standard
             input instead of using the terminal device.  The password must be followed by a
             newline character.
```

You should use this option in sudo.

best regards